# Typescript Generics return type based on argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How to do dynamic typescript return type based on an argument is undefined or not. Please help.

Also added a [Typescript Playground Snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBDIKMjJBhLHDwADy0gAVpBYKgADw4AB8oAA3ooSgBteL5K6oSicZgAXVFOAA3IoAL7BBCcQQ0dCMlls0AAXlAnP4ADU9aAABTxSCGVI4ACUXLNArcQlQssFUt4TsteFF3qJOE9JR0DGg7EgAGkrQB%20UVGxS2vU84OhiNWvW6-VcbiQZIZSDcJ0lKPO9UBJzcdgWM1mkPQfiwfEJ3U8s38krt0ABLu1wMd0CChtkYVWqViYRceIDCReBjCdUS6WiweF0CK238XmKsfeBnM1kc7m2lei6Ausv5yuQas9kyNxPmtt9rsBHsroWD4d4Uez0ATqczudxWGGVbyHZMw0jPBtz-eBp23P0bSlFc1w3LcfzpLV905T9-SlLlbQVYJFApb5qSWAAROoGEfBhRXnYYFRKaQ6KAyVGJMFiFwVZVVXVEtXVASjUAYd1TUFJ1eVogByBgpP4ZjQCk6Q5I4xTYCkxVe0k-IpIARhUhSpIAJhU2BRSkgBmDTFClQiVHYQQUF0xRePgdwAmgeBmDNTU9zZdkhIYB1T3VfgZKk20COKAkCEaRzin5FQSl5cLRW08L5PM5T6x09TFU0mY%20T0qS0uk-TMuM0zzJM-LPRUZVigAUUeR56UeMoeQAYTMGhuAwIZfhUXjeqogBZBgCFlXdtQ5QKeX1XyZoCqjgpdMLZKilR9kUjC-NmlbQAAHx3TD-PoyUuSkkRhAGGhZzkZhOAYaR3DBVB2h26asLmqSgi2j6pN2pbzuYS7rv6QYxwep6XssfqAaB76Vt%204ptqkkGrtEW6oYoR7nteqx3qIRTAt%20s0jIsoyjKPYp7kc0AjJcuK3MgDyvJ8r7-Lms0QtQdaVKUiLNuAGK4qUFReSK2Sso0jdiuqjTV2CFRmta9rSi6nq4X6tRBuAYa4SoyDxsmk69vZEH5uWU79uE1bQsU2SwuU4XiRQQHOdtoKjrN4HWNBzGbsh%207cZhgn4eJj2bYt-3Lr%20sA0cRrnkfB7GQ7x2G3oRz2Y4XOPUYB0nU%20DwRofxuG0ABjGAnJynqaIrbmg8MgvEQeA%20mejgNTuRhJXYBhmEgetT1gRJO70EQvAAIka1YGEQBZ9CnpJsSn8AHFQdHQAAOUgCQp-j0B6S%20Mh3kc-hB6OYSyAUVxpCgpw250YYsH0FAEEQaFhEuL5JHb6JwaGHxPMRgLA2BZiCEAA) for reference

I have come up with this, but is not working as expected.

```
V extends keyof T ? ToObject<T> : ToObject<T[keyof T]>
```

> The code:

```js
export interface ToObject<T> {
  [k: string]: T;
}

export const toObject = <T, V = (keyof T)>(
  list: T[],
  key: keyof T,
  valueKey?: V
): V extends keyof T ? ToObject<T> : ToObject<T[keyof T]> => valueKey === undefined
    ? list.reduce((all, cur) => ({
      ...all,
      [cur[key] as unknown as string]: cur
    }), {} as ToObject<T>)
    : list.reduce((all, cur) => ({
      ...all,
      [cur[key] as unknown as string]: cur[valueKey as unknown as keyof T]
    }), {} as ToObject<T[keyof T]>);
```

> Usage :

```js
interface Data{
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
}
const list: Data[] = [
  {a:'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'},
  {a:'1', b: '2', c: '3'}
];

// use 1
toObject<Data>(list, 'a');
// response
{
  {'a': {a:'a', b: 'b', c:'c'}},
  {'1': {a:'1', b:'2', c: '2'}},
}

// Use 2
toObject<Data>(list, 'a', 'b');
//response
{ {'a': 'b'}, {'1': '2'} }
```

> ISSUE:

```js
// use 1 ERROR -> Cant do this
const dataMap: ToObject<Data> = toObject<Data>(list, 'a');
// Type 'ToObject<Data> | ToObject<string>' is not assignable to type 'ToObject<Data>'.
// Type 'ToObject<string>' is not assignable to type 'ToObject<Data>'.
// Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Data'.(2322)

// Use 2 ERROR -> Cant do this
const dataKeyMap: ToObject<string> = toObject<Data>(list, 'a', 'b');
// Type 'ToObject<Data> | ToObject<string>' is not assignable to type 'ToObject<string>'.
// Type 'ToObject<Data>' is not assignable to type 'ToObject<string>'.
// Type 'Data' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, TS does not have enough information differentiate between `toObject`'s two return types.

If we add [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), we can tie a return type to a function signature.  If `valueKey` is passed,
`toObject` returns `ToObject<T[keyof T]>`, if not, then the function returns `ToObject<T>`.

[Revised Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBDIKMjJBhLHDwADy0gAVpBYKgADw4AB8oAA3ooSgBteL5K6oSicZgAXVFOAA3IoAL7BZJcNkNJqMlls0Cc-gANVAAF5QAAKeKQQypHAASi5pugQlQssFUv4Frwoo9RNtsoZzNZHO5ilV5nqjWWWsDupwBuNZu91rtDqdLrdoA9XstPv4OgY0HYkAA0pbRfqbX6o2zOcLs9apVyQ2rw5qAzq9aBDSbzXXvMnHYJnd5Xe7Sxne7HQHmC8XLQB+MsV7z+7VBnkAH2XVaDtat3gbfIFoCcqHxXmnhZLeGNRpNXG4kGSGUg3CPJTnbidASc3HYFlNpr5tA-CwPiNrGjypr8iUMGgAE8FAbwb4wYKoFkLuUpiMIXDxAMEheAwwiDhK0qimhyGKja-C8oqWFbm2a42shooDqg34vn+kAAYhJhgRBZrQbBcEIdAwHIUKaEYXROF4QRRHisMMq8ehF6ztehGgDJ8D4XRib7hRVF8rRGl0tuNZ6TgDY2gqtElMEigUt81JLAAInUDCCQworEcMColNI3kKZKfkmIFJE2YoCCcIOn6DqKbmoAwrrxoKR68l5ADkDAZfwAWgBl0g5aF+WwBlipISU6X5BlACMRV5RlABMRWwKKGUAMxlYoUoKsU7CCCgNWRY0gjwO4ATQPAzCmugZkJQw9qsfwWUZTa1nFASBAjUoKj8iolUraKVUrblbWFSB1WlYq5UzHytUZUdmV1adTUtW1zXXUhKjKsUACijyPPSjxlDyADCZg0NwGBDL8UUxdw7kALIMAQlYMey808ias3o5jKaDst2XrSo+z5aZuPuRu9GruyPmSlyGUiMIAw0IRcjMJwDDSO4YKoO0ZMroGGOUxlQQk-zGXkzTdPMAzTP9IMWHs5z3OWNDEtS0LmOi8UpMZTLjOiCzSsUBzXM81YfNEPl82i6ajXtY1jVMcU9wDaAjXDdFY2QBNU0zYL1Z40t+XZcthVrQqICbdtxS8nd2VnWV1H3e9ZWgD9Kj-YDwOlGDENwtDaiwyNkPuVeyOo9TQsy1jkYU4li1OoTRUFatUdgHrmtB5ToCbt3HK14bzOK2zpsqxb6vW5LgeD0Fss6+L08D8LjfDwrrOCMr5tq2gGuz7T88M2LncS7b8vG2PZuq7zEsGwE9uO879kk80HhkF4iDwH0XMcDQXxuDMMwdgDBmCQBAo6WAiRf56BEF4AARL9VYDBEALH0PApI2J4HgAcKgfWoAABykAJDwJPqAekXwyDvAGvwMBRxEpkAUK4aQ14nBfx0MMLA+gUAIEQNCYQlwAESG-tEeWhh8TzEYCwNg94ghAA)

```js
export function toObject <T, V = (keyof T)>(list: T[], key: keyof T): ToObject<T>
export function toObject <T, V = (keyof T)>(list: T[], key: keyof T, valueKey: V): ToObject<T[keyof T]>
export function toObject <T, V = (keyof T)>(list: T[], key: keyof T, valueKey?: V): ToObject<T> | ToObject<T[keyof T]> {
  return valueKey === undefined
    ? list.reduce((all, cur) => ({
      ...all,
      [cur[key] as unknown as string]: cur
    }), {} as ToObject<T>)
    : list.reduce((all, cur) => ({
      ...all,
      [cur[key] as unknown as string]: cur[valueKey as unknown as keyof T]
    }), {} as ToObject<T[keyof T]>);
}
```

In addition to making the TS compiler happy, the overloads also inform human users how they should call the function.

Comment: ok, how can i add these to `export const toObject = () =>{}` since I import this function to another ts file

Comment: Easy, peasy.  Append the word `export` before the three `toObject` signatures (see edits above).  This function overload style does not work with arrow functions,  so I refactored `toObject` as function declaration.

Comment: @fedonev Arrow function overload: ```export const toObject: {
  <T, V = (keyof T)>(list: T[], key: keyof T): ToObject<T>
  <T, V = (keyof T)>(list: T[], key: keyof T, valueKey: V): ToObject<T[keyof T]>
} = <T, V = (keyof T)>(list: T[], key: keyof T, valueKey?: V): ToObject<T> | ToObject<T[keyof T]> => {
  ...
}
```